# challenge_ts missing in ReCaptcha validation response

Tags: validation, recaptcha

The response from the ReCaptcha V2 validation API used to contain the parameter challenge_ts (for a "stale" recaptcha), but it no longer does. Here's a sample response body I am getting back:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error-codes": ["timeout-or-duplicate"]
}
```

I am pretty sure this has started fairly recently, in the last few weeks. However, I could not find anything official on this change. Is anyone else seeing this?

Does anyone know what may have changed?

Comment: i have the same issue